# Running SUM per unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the one below.

```
q_id    Fails   
1         0 
1         0 
1         2 
2         3 
3         0 
3         3 
4        10
```

For each ID, I want to output the total overall fail per q_id like shown below. I've tried the SUM/COUNT operation, but couldn't get it to give the same output as below.

```
q_id    fails   running_fail
1         0          2
1         0          2
1         2          2
2         1          1
3         0          3
3         3          3
4        10          10
```

EDIT: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'm using windows server 2008

Comment: Can you add some more detail/example data? Your data looks like it could be either the highest fail number or the last fail number.

Comment: A running sum is usually the sum of all items up to that row, but it seems you only want the total on each row. Could you clarify?

Comment: I wanted to add the Fail column for each q_id, have have it displayed per row. I've got the answer that i needed. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select q_id, fails, sum(fails) over (partition by q_id) from yourtable;
```

If your current RDBMS support window functions.

If not then you can try this:

```
select
  q_id,
  fails,
  (select sum(fails) from yourtable t2 where t2.q_id=t1.q_id)
from
  yourtable t1;
```